# Writing a library for Unity apps

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm completely new to Unity. I would like to write a library that Unity developers can use in their apps. This library will need to communicate with a server, store and retrieve structured data, and display form or web views that can be interacted with to the user. I will not require any fancy graphics behavior.

From the skimming I've done on the Unity documentation, it looks like Unity Plugins are more for lower level behavior than I'm looking for. I would like to be able to write this plugin in C#, and reuse as much code across platforms as possible.

I would love some pointers on resources or tutorials to checkout.

Comment: Please use unity3d tag.

Answer (score 2):

In Unity, libraries are written in distributed in form of [Unity packages](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/HOWTO-exportpackage.html). It's essentially nothing more then a collection of files from your project. They are used by [Unity Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/), where you can distribute your library for money or for free.

To get a grasp on them, try importing popular packages like the animation engine [iTween](http://itween.pixelplacement.com/) or interface solution [NGUI](http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=140). You'll see that when developers are selling their libraries and don't want source to be open, they use [compiled DLLs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/UsingDLL.html) instead of just providing source files.

Comment: Great, thanks for these pointers. I'll take a look. My library will be open source, so hopefully that won't be a problem.